# How to check if Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events is enabled

Tags: apex, tasks, activity-settings

In the activity settings you can turn on or off Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events. But how can I check this in my Apex code? I thought it might be in the Organization table but I dont see anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `Setup` > `Customize` > `Activities` > `Activity Settings`.

The last checkbox in the list is called `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events`. Helptext:

> Enabling this feature lets users relate up to 50 contacts to a task or event (except a recurring task or event).

---

From `Apex`, you can inspect the global describe to see if a specific `sObjectType` is supported:

```
Boolean isTaskRelationEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('TaskRelation');
```

Comment: I can see that alright when I navigate there. But if Im doing apex code that will use the TaskRelation table then that table will only exist if that checkbox is checked. So I need to be able to check if it is on or off from Apex

Comment: @discodowney Updated my answer. It didn't look like you necessarily needed a programmatic solution at first glance.

Comment: Cheers Adrian. Works perfectly.

Comment: Will above query work for Event also ? I can see EventRelation object is already available even multiple contact setting is disabled.